# Custom presenter for the EVR in Windows Media Foundation

Tags: audio, video, ms-media-foundation

If I would like to feed the presenter/VMR with the frames that should be rendered as soon as they are delivered.
1.) How can I send frames to presenter?
2.) Do I have to implement my own presenter in that case?
It's unbelievable, the entire MSDN doesn't say one word on when or why to implement your own presenter.

Answer (score 1):

1. To present samples immediately you just need to remove time stamps from them
2. No you don't need custom allocator/presenter just for this purpose
3. There have been custom allocator/presenter samples for VMR-7, VMR-9, [for EVR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb970434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so basically there is something to start from, and MSDN also [provides quite some details on the topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the information might just be sparse across various SDKs and sections

Bottom line: you don't need and perhaps you should rather not do custom a/p before you clearly understand what it is for.

Something useful for you from [earlier topics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about custom allocator/presenters:

> In renderless playback mode, the VMR does not perform the rendering.
>   Instead, it uses a custom allocator-presenter supplied by the
>   application. **This mode is useful for** games and other types of
>   applications that have sophisticated video effects. Renderless
>   playback mode enables the applications to create and control its own
>   DirectDraw surface (VMR-7) or Direct3D surface (VMR-9), and to access
>   the video bits at presentation time.

Comment: Since I did read most of the documentation and I still don't see an answer to "when to implement your own presenter", could you please provide a short answer to that. It seems like you know the answer. I did see the link you mention. As I said, it explains HOW to implement your own presenter, not WHY. Also, the question on how to feed the presenter still remains...

Comment: Custom A/P is an extensibility option. You need it when you can't live with the default one for whatever reason, and it's not so trivial to elaborate such a requirement. For example, you want to manage Direct3D surfaces yourself, reuse them or combine with some other application activity - this is where you need it.

Comment: When you mention VMR, that applies to DirectShow? In WMF, video is being rendered by the EVR, right? I'm working on non DShow solution.

Comment: EVR's presenters are suitable for both DirectShow and MF, so if you are looking for background when and why presenters are used, this general DirectShow information still applies.